# Change catalog images size magento

Tags: css, image, magento, categories, catalog

I am trying to change the size of my catalog images. I changed the css and also used the resize function

```
<?php 
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(196); ?>" width="135" height="296" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
</a>
```

But it didn't work. It seems like my template has properties for the category images declared. In the code the category products have size applied to them:245x245. I have been looking everywhere to change it but nothing worked. I saw that magento go lets you overwrite the the default size and proportion of any catalog image in the back end. But I don't see the same in the community..

Comment: Please put your code inside `` (the button under the esc. key) Or press the { } code button.

Comment: Did you check on the frontend where that is being displayed, may be some extensions are installed which are overriding the default properties.

Answer (score 0):

The physical image size change, but because image width and height is set using html it will not change.

Change

> src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(196); ?>" width="135" height="296"

To

> src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(196); ?>" **width="196" height="196"**